# Grails 3.1.8 : Spring Rest Docs using Rest Assured giving PayloadHandlingException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException

Tags: json, grails, rest-assured, asciidoc, spring-restdocs

I'm trying to implement ascii doc with snippet for grails rest-api with rest-assured for json response :

```
    {
  "instanceList": [
    {
      "firstName": "Coy",
      "lastName": "T",
      "pictureUrl": null,
      "email": "bootstrap@cc.com",
      "bio": null,
      "skills": [],
      "interestAreas": []
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Jane",
      "lastName": "D",
      "pictureUrl": null,
      "email": "jane@cc.com",
      "bio": null,
      "skills": [],
      "interestAreas": []
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Cause",
      "lastName": "C",
      "pictureUrl": "https://cc-picture.com",
      "email": "cc-user@code.com",
      "bio": "cc beyond infinity",
      "skills": [],
      "interestAreas": []
    },
    {
      "firstName": "sachidanand",
      "lastName": "v",
      "pictureUrl": null,
      "email": "cc@cc.com",
      "bio": null,
      "skills": [],
      "interestAreas": []
    }
  ],
  "totalCount": 4
}
```

and the code snippet of UserDocumentationApiSpec(as IntegrationTest) :

```
void 'test and document get request for /user'() {
        expect:
        given(documentationSpec)
                .header("AuthToken", "TokenValue")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString())
                .filter(document('user-list-v1',
                preprocessRequest(modifyUris()
                        .host('127.0.0.1')
                        .removePort()),
                preprocessResponse(prettyPrint()),
                responseFields(
                        fieldWithPath("[].firstName").description("First name of user"),
                        fieldWithPath("[].lastName").description("Last name of user"),
                        fieldWithPath("[].pictureUrl").type(JsonFieldType.STRING).description("Picture Url of user"),
                        fieldWithPath("[].email").description("Email address of user"),
                        fieldWithPath("[].bio").description("Bio data of user"),
                        fieldWithPath("totalCount").description("Count of instanceList field"),
                        fieldWithPath("type").description("Type of result")
                ))).
                when()
                .port(8080)
                .get('/api/v1/user')
                .then()
                .assertThat()
                .statusCode(is(200))
    }
```

This part of code giving me error trace as :

```
org.springframework.restdocs.payload.PayloadHandlingException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: [B@2c6adbe3; line: 1, column: 1]
    at org.springframework.restdocs.payload.JsonContentHandler.readContent(JsonContentHandler.java:84)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.payload.JsonContentHandler.findMissingFields(JsonContentHandler.java:50)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.payload.AbstractFieldsSnippet.validateFieldDocumentation(AbstractFieldsSnippet.java:113)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.payload.AbstractFieldsSnippet.createModel(AbstractFieldsSnippet.java:74)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.TemplatedSnippet.document(TemplatedSnippet.java:64)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.generate.RestDocumentationGenerator.handle(RestDocumentationGenerator.java:192)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.restassured.RestDocumentationFilter.filter(RestDocumentationFilter.java:63)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:73)
    at com.jayway.restassured.filter.session.SessionFilter.filter(SessionFilter.java:60)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:73)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.restassured.RestAssuredRestDocumentationConfigurer.filter(RestAssuredRestDocumentationConfigurer.java:65)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:73)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1574)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:159)
    at com.converge.docs.UserApiDocumentationSpec.$tt__$spock_feature_0_0(UserApiDocumentationSpec.groovy:73)
    at com.converge.docs.UserApiDocumentationSpec.test and document get request for /user_closure2(UserApiDocumentationSpec.groovy)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:426)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:442)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$1.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:70)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.executeAndRollback(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:67)
    at com.converge.docs.UserApiDocumentationSpec.test and document get request for /user(UserApiDocumentationSpec.groovy)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: [B@2c6adbe3; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3781)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3721)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2819)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.payload.JsonContentHandler.readContent(JsonContentHandler.java:81)
    ... 21 more
```

Please correct me where I'm going wrong...

Comment: It looks like the response from the get request to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/user` isn't valid JSON. If you curl it, what response do you get?

Comment: Hitting `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/user` from **Rest Client** I'm getting proper **json** response as above, 200 ok status

Comment: The response shown in your question isn't valid JSON

Comment: Updated the **Json response** @here

Comment: That looks OK. I can't spot anything else that's obviously wrong. Can you share a [minimal example](/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason I see for this failing is that you are not getting the expected response from the `/api/v1/user` endpoint.

Follow these steps:

1. Check that instances are there in the database.
2. Check that you are sending the correct token.
3. Write a test case using the RestBuilder and see if you actually get the expected response.

Your code and JSON looks fine.

Also, make sure you follow this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/96) and mark your empty array field as optional and explicitly provide a type for its contents.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue!!, the `token` I was passing was incorrect and hence response was not there. Also, the issue you mentioned, I followed that and added content type to arrays that responded empty.

Answer (score 1):

I frequently see the error: `org.springframework.restdocs.payload.PayloadHandlingException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input`

When there is no response. I see this is a `get` request.  These integration tests work a little bit differently in Grails than RestClient. Have you setup a sample data point in this test or in the bootstrap.Groovy file? I can't see the rest of the code see how you are running this as an integration test.  In my sample Grails example, I setup some test data in the [Bootstrap.groovy](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/blob/master/samples/rest-notes-grails/grails-app/init/BootStrap.groovy) file.

Please let me know if I can help.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the response was not there.